# Making a new account on Minecraft pc

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I asked the same question before but the only answer I got was that it was 'unclear'. Fair enough. I just down loaded Minecraft, and when I go onto it, it tells me to log in or sign. I click sign up. But once I've filled out all of my details and click register, it fades and nothing happens. I have tried several times and each time the same thing happens, which means I can't play. Why is it just fading and doing nothing?? What do I need to do to fix it??

Comment: As far as i know you need to have: 1) an account on the minecraft website 2) buy minecraft with that account. At this point you can use your login to play the game. Do you meet these requirements? this is probably part of why your old question was branded as unclear.

Comment: Is there a default browser set in your system? Maybe it tries to open that and can't for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you press the register function in the client you downloaded but since the only thing that button does is redirect you to the mojang website, I would suggest you go directly to the website and register your account there.

[Minecraft Website](https://minecraft.net/)

After you register and purchase the game there you should be able to login to the client using the details you just entered.